# Linux bash read from a file then adduser to linux

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, pam

I want to add linux users then i want to restrict them as hard as possible. (noshell etc) from a file called users.

This is my code but not working:

```
    while read line
    do
input = echo ($input | tr ":" "\n")

        #!/bin/bash
        # Script to add a user to Linux system
        if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$username exists!"
                exit 1
            else
                pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $input[1)
                useradd -m -p $input[1] $input[0]
                [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
            fi
        else
            echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
            exit 2
        fi
    done < /var/www/users
```

Then i want to restrict their accounts with noshell. (but i know how can i do. But i cant separate the input from the file correctly :/)

input(users):

```
john:lol
rambo:sanyi
cula:kari
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like Mandar has answered your question, but for future reference, the shebang line `#!/bin/bash` should be the very _first_ line of your script. It's useless buried in the middle of your script. So you need to be a bit more careful when creating scripts by copy & paste. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, following script will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERS=`cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1`

if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Login as Root"
else
    while read line
    do
        USER=`echo $line | cut -d ":" -f1`
        PASS=`echo $line | cut -d ":" -f2`

        echo $USERS | grep "${USER}" > /dev/null

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "Username ${USER} Exists!"
        else
            password=`perl -e 'print crypt("${PASS}", "salt")', "\n"`
            useradd -p "${password}" ${USER}

            echo "User ${USER} created!"
        fi

        i+=1
    done < /var/www/users
fi
```

Comment: Dont know why, but when i create an user with this, he isnt able to authenticate (with ssh, or with openvpn (PAM auth) )

Comment: but if i:passwd gyuri to the loller it is working normally. So it is a problem with the password. Or with my knowledge :)